# spring-hateoas with `use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false` still response `application/hal+json` by default

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hal-json

I want to disable HAL format by default.

Flow the document, I set this property.

```
spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false
```

Then test it:

**1. Request with header `Accept: application/json`.**

Header: `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Response:

```
{
  "links": {}
}
```

**2. Request with header `Accept: */*` or without `Accept` header.**

Header: `Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8`

Response:

```
{
  "_embedded": {},
  "_links": {}
}
```

The version of `spring-boot` is 1.5.3, and I use `spring-boot-starter-hateoas`.

Is anyway let hateoas to response json without HAL when no header specified?

Thanks a lot.

---

**Update:**

Here is a example base on [the guide from spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/).

Requests at: `http://localhost:8080/greeting`

Requests with header `Accept: */*`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8

{
  "content":"Hello, World!",
  "_links":{
    "self":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=World"
    }
  }
}
```

Requests with header `Accept: application/json`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
  "content":"Hello, World!",
  "_links":{
    "self":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=World"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want HAL by default, so I add a config file `resources/application.properties` to the project.

```
spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false
```

And test again.

Requests with header `Accept: */*`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8

{
  "content":"Hello, World!",
  "_links":{
    "self":{
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=World"
    }
  }
}
```

Requests with header `Accept: application/json`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
  "content":"Hello, World!",
  "links":[
    {
      "rel":"self",
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=World"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for people to help you, can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) for your problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson OK, here is a example.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the sort of example I was looking for. As described on the page that I linked to, I was looking for some code that can easily be run to reproduce the problem. I link to a repository on GitHub would be ideal.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The code was noticed in the doc. 1) Download and unzip the source repository for this guide, or clone it using Git: git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-hateoas.git  2) cd into gs-rest-hateoas/initial , run gradlew or mvnw  3) When you’re finished, you can check your results against the code in gs-rest-hateoas/complete.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Excuse me, is there any result?

Comment: You've misunderstood the property. It has no affect when you're accepting */*. It just controls whether application/hal+json _may_ be served if you ask for application/json